# Is there a cheaper way to do load testing than upgrading to Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio, profiling, load-testing

I have a Visual Studio 2010 Professional license so Ultimate is a long way off and all I want it for is load testing for a few weeks or so.

Is there a cheaper way of getting just the load testing part of VS2010 ultimate or an alternate load testing tool with decent metrics of how the load testing is doing? I'd like to know pages/sec, page speed, database connections and less important: CPU, memory, errors.

Comment: Ultimate might not be the way to go anyway as it only allows a limited amount of Local users in the load testing tool, you need to buy the Remote user pack to point it at a remote server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have always found that the Radview Webload tool gives a good alternative but you will probably need to set up performance counters for CPU etc... and tie the data together yourself.  Have you considered using an evaluation version of Ultimate to check if that would meet you needs? ;)

Comment: I hadn't thought of getting the evaluation copy, no. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

We developed a free Fiddler extension for load testing called [StresStimulus](http://stresstimulus.stimulustechnology.com). It replays sessions recorded in Fiddler under varied load levels and measures performance metrics. It is not nearly as complete as testing tools in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, but satisfies some of your requirements. You can get requests per/s and response times. The interface with PerfMon is not ready yet, so Windows performance counters should be tied manually.

Comment: It is worth noting that StressStimulus is no longer free.

Comment: It looks like there is a free version, as well as paid versions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set up [Instrumentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300488.aspx) on your app?